# Loading external json file in highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

When loading external JSON file in HighCharts it shows nothing in the browser. I have following JSON data. I have included highchart.js and jquery.js in the `head` of my HTML code, but still I cannot get a bar chart in my browser. No error is shown in console when checking the console.

```
var json = [{
    "key": "Apples",
    "value": "4"
}, {
    "key": "Pears",
    "value": "7"
}, {
    "key": "Bananas",
    "value": "9"
}];

var processed_json = new Array();
$.map(json, function(obj, i) {
    processed_json.push([obj.key, parseInt(obj.value)]);
});

$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: "category"
    },
    series: [{
        data: processed_json
    }]
});
```

Comment: Try with static data instead of json file and check if it works , might be data issue.

Comment: not work when json data is used inside <script>

Answer (score 0):

That is because the order of execution is different than we expect. ie The JSON loading section execution is happening before it get initialized.

You can put the JSON loading section code in one function and call that function after initialization function is completed(.success or .done in the HTML element's event).

I had one AJax function so I called this JSON loading function in the success of that AJAX call.

Code:

```
var json = [{
    "key": "Apples",
    "value": "4"
}, {
    "key": "Pears",
    "value": "7"
}, {
    "key": "Bananas",
    "value": "9"
}];

var processed_json = new Array();
$.map(json, function(obj, i) {
    processed_json.push([obj.key, parseInt(obj.value)]);
});
if (processed_json.length != 0) {
   loadJson();
}

function loadJson() {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: "category"
        },
        series: [{
            data: processed_json
        }]
    });
}
```

Comment: not understand what you mean? Explain with code #Sanjay Kumar N S

Comment: Make sure that element with id = container is present and the JSON variable processed_json is initialized properly.

Comment: yes id = container is present in <div>. Can you provide the output with JSFiddle

Comment: Here I could find that the variable processed_json is not in a valid JSON format which you are expecting. When I tried with the variable json, its working. I don't have your full code, even then I tried with a sample.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sanjaykumarns/VtVFB/612/