# How can i load external JSON data in highchart to show bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, charts, highcharts

This is my JSON format data. Here,country_Name should be in y-axis and value should be displayed in x-axis. I am searching this answer last 2 days,but i can't loaded the external JSON data in Highcharts to show the bar charts.I need dynamic bar chart,while changing my JSON data automatically change my bar chart. I done the following code,but it only show the title,subtitle and y-axis text but not showing the bar chart. Also the coded is shown below.

```
 [
{
    "Country_Name": "MYANMAR",
    "value": [
        143
    ]
},
{
    "Country_Name": "MONGOLIA",
    "value": [
        46
    ]
},
{
    "Country_Name": "ZIMBABWE",
    "value": [
        1
    ]
},
{
    "Country_Name": "Bahrain",
    "value": [
        1
    ]
}
]

         $.getJSON('recipient_country.json', function(data) {

    console.log(data);

    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Recipient Country'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: aidstream.org'
        },
        xAxis: {
           title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Country Name',
                align: 'high'
            },
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return ''+
                    this.series.Country_Name +': '+ this.y +' activities';
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -100,
            y: 100,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            shadow: true
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: data
    });
  });
  });
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24608983/how-can-i-load-external-json-file-in-highcharts-for-making-bar-chart

Comment: And one more duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24606089/loading-external-json-file-in-highchart

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i load external json file in highcharts for making bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24608983/how-can-i-load-external-json-file-in-highcharts-for-making-bar-chart)